# Rails : How to display a post in a blog for normal users out side the post controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my app, there's a seperate admin area to control everything including writing posts. The post routes point inside the admin panel :

```
resources :posts, path: '/admindashboard/posts'
```

Now in the normal view, Im trying to display the posts inside the **pages controller** under the **blog action**. I have managed to list the posts in the blog. But linking to them and showing individual posts is the problem.

Not : I use a post slug instead of the id.

If I link to the post like this :

```
<%= link_to post.title, post  %>
```

It will go to /admindashboard/posts/post-slug. But to access that url, we need to sign in. I need to put it like /blog/post-slug . How to do it? How to add the right action in the pages controller to display individual post pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [namespacing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) like this

```
namespace :admindashboard do
  resources :posts
end
```

Comment: When I say   "scope :module => "blog" do
    resources :posts, path: '/blog'
  end "  It say "uninitialized constant Blog"

Comment: Perfect. Then I will have to add the following code for the blog "  scope "/blog" do
    resources :posts
  end"  No issue to have two routes like this?

Comment: Is there a way to display individual posts in the pages controller without going to posts controller?

Comment: I would have the resources for posts under admin like I showed above, and then add another singular resource http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources to the post outside of admindashboard like this: match 'post' => "pages#post' (or another controller) to fetch and show the post you want.

Comment: How to use another controller to fetch the posts? I tried to do it but how to handle dynamic URLS? For example, if we directly call the resource posts, it will auto generate URLS for invidiual posts like /posts/first_post . But If I go to /blog/first_post it say missing routes!